# How can I show some links/navigation to logged in users in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help with wordpress. I will show a login box on my main page and if some registered user logs in, I want to show some links/navigation to that person only (not to guests). Is that possible? If yes then how? Please guide me with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the conditional check `is_user_logged_in()`:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ){
   // The user is logged in
} else {
  // They're not logged in
}
```

This will work any time after the 'init' hook.